# Django Material Autocomplete

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, material-design, django-autocomplete-light

Has anyone managed to get an Autocomplete working for Django Material https://github.com/viewflow/django-material? I really like the look of the interface for the admin and all I require is an autocomplete widget to work as my tables are too big.

I have tried Django Select2 and Autocomplete-light but it seems like the django-material doesn't render the widgets. The error I get for autocomplete-light is the same as [Django material with django smart select error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977194/django-material-with-django-smart-select-error) and then for django-select2 there is no error, but the widget doesn't render.

Comment: Were you able to get Django Select2 and Autocomplete-light to work?

Comment: No. I stopped using django material as most of the useful functionality is paid for only.